# How to convert an id to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{username}}_corresponding_employee_id" name="{{username}}_corresponding_employee_id" value="{{employee_id}}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="{{lowercase_username}}_corresponding_employee_id" name="{{lowercase_username}}_corresponding_employee_id" value="{{employee_id}}"/>
```

I need an id to be in both all lowercase and normal format so that I can get the employee_id like this:

```
$('#' + username + '_corresponding_employee_id').val();
```

So if `username` were `john1234` or `John1234`, both would give me the same employee_id.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using mustache to generate the `username` in HTML, and I'm using javascript to generate the mustache.

Comment: Is this a HTML question, or are you using some backend system to generate HTML for you? Your question doesn't provide any detail about the background of the problem.

Comment: Edited my post. I'm using javascript to generate my mustache, and ultimately my HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#' + username.toLowerCase() + '_corresponding_employee_id').val()
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Rc2/)

Just type some username containing uppercase letters.

If you really want to use `{{}}`. As you cannot assign `{{username}}` to javascript code, you need to create `hidden` `input` for it. You may do something like this:

*HTML :*

```
<input type="hidden" name="username_{{employee_id}}" value="{{username}}" />
    <input type="hidden" rel="corresponding_employee_id" value="{{employee_id}}"/>
```

*jQuery :*

```
$.each($('input[rel="corresponding_employee_id"]'),function(){
    $(this).attr('id',$('input[name="username_'+$(this).val()+']').val().toLowerCase()+'_corresponding_employee_id').attr('name',$('input[name="username_'+$(this).val()+']').val().toLowerCase()+'_corresponding_employee_id');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm being clear enough with my question. I need to somehow convert `username` in my html to `lowercase_username`

Comment: Check example... if it is in hidden input, example gives what You want.